# How can I make the image uploaded to the schema into a background in CSS?

Tags: html, css, shopify, themes

I am trying to make the uploaded picture into a background in Shopify Themes

```
<div class="collection-card" style="background-image: url('{{ section.blocks[0].settings.image }}')">
```

Comment: Hi there. What does the path of the image say when you check console or source? Is it *actually* uploaded? FTP or via form?

Comment: HI, yes. It is uploaded. i ;m just trying to make the uploaded photo in the schema into a background

Comment: What about the path then?

Comment: You need to share the code also for schema, and another code of page here

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an image filter to get url with parameters.
For example:

```
{{ section.blocks[0].settings.image | image_url: width: 1920 }}
```

More information about image filters here:
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/filters/image_url